# How to make transparent navigate bar with Table View Cell

Tags: swift, uitableview, tableview, navigationbar

I faced with the Table View Cells issue. If I choose default View Controller settings,  cells are located  under transparent navigation Bar. This is unacceptable because bars items overlap the cell.

[navigation bar overload the tableView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSgei.jpg)

If I changing Extend Edges setting at the tab on the right side, specifically "Under Top Bars", cells as expected are located under bar, but in this case NavigateBar is black.

[navigation Bar is black](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dn7d2.png)

As you see I tried to fix that issue with the Simulated Metrics, but nothing is chanced. Also `self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true` and `self.navigationController?.view.backgroundColor = .clear` in `viewDidLoad` method did't give any result. I able to color navigation Bar, but i need it transparent. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you haven't set a background color to the ViewController's view. That's why it's appearing black.
Try adding the background color you want and it should work as expected.

Comment: Hi! In my case, there should be an Image on the background. Do you know how to set it for full screen? I can set background image only for tableView and the navigateBar still  is black.

Comment: What did you try so far do accomplish it?